# laravel query join with only latest record

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using **Laravel 5.3** and trying to return a heist with it's product and only the **latest order** and with the **latest price history**. Both joins don't return anything but if I remove the `$q->latest()->first();` and replace it with a simple `orderBy()` I get all results. My query is:

```
$data = $heist->with(['product'=> function($query) {
  $query->with(['orders' => function($q) {
    return $q->latest()->first();
  }]);
  $query->with(['price_history' => function($q) {
    return $q->latest()->first();
  }]);
}])->orderBy('completed_at', 'DESC')->orderBy('active', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried giving `first()` like so `->orderBy('active', 'DESC')->first()` at the end?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the heists not just the first one. I only want the latest of the joined models.

Comment: Well, then please reformat the question. It says **only latest _record_**

Comment: @Jongo Can you please write down the relations between the tables? and explain a bit more on the term `latest`... Like @linuxartisan said, I believe `orderBy('id','desc')` is equal to `latest()`

Comment: Heist has one Product and Product has many Order and has many PriceHistory. I tried to make the question as clear as possible.  I want all heists with their product but only the latest Order and the latest PriceHistory. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: from my understanding, latest()->first() would the same as orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(1) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Calling first() is the same as calling take(1)->get()[0]; 
Which means limit the amount returned to 1 and return it. What you want is just the limit part. So if you change first() to take(1).

**Update**

```
$data = $heist->with([
    'product'=> function($query) {
       $query->with(
            [
                'orders' => function($q) {
                   $q->latest()->take(1);
                },
                'price_history' => function($q) {
                   $q->latest()->take(1);
                }
            ]
        );
    }
])->orderBy('completed_at', 'DESC')->orderBy('active', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: This works but only on the first heist in the results - which is similar to what I was getting with $q->latest()->first(). The price history on the first result is empty and all the other heists in the results have both orders and price history are an empty.

Comment: @Jongo Try out this now. I believe you dont need to return the relation rules, and also you dont need to call `->get()`. And if you still get the same result can you call `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` on the very end of the query so we can further investigate.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, I believe the simplest way of doing this is

```
$heists = $heist->with(['product'=> function($query) {
  $query->with([
    'orders' => function($q) {
      return $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
    },
    'price_history' => function($q) {
      return $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
    }
  ]);
}])->orderBy('completed_at', 'desc')->orderBy('active', 'desc')->get();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Same issue as below - it works for the first heist result (for the orders but not price history) but all other results have empty arrays for orders and price history

Comment: the result looks something like: [{"id":1,"product_id":32594763262,"orders":[{"id":8827,"product_id":32594763262, "created_at":"2016-11-14 04:43:50","updated_at":"2016-11-14 04:43:50"}],"price_history":[]},
{"id":2,"product_id":32742307067, "orders":[], "price_history":[]}]

Comment: @Jongo If a row is not present in your orders table or price_history related to that particular `product_id`, the collection will obviously be empty. Are you trying to just get the latest order and price_history be it of any product into the collection?

Comment: I'm trying to get the latest order and price history of the product that it is related to and there are rows there because if I change the join query to $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') it works and returns all related rows in the correct order.

Comment: It just seems to be the limiting it to the latest record that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Jongo I am asking this again - When you say `latest`, do you not mean the most recently placed order/price_history for that product? Also, you want one record or all records sorted by most recent to the least?